# Accesing globally defined data from within functions - best practices, know-how?

Tags: php, global-variables

I've just recently started to code in PHP, and the thing that got me really confused is global variables - I seem to not be able to access global variables/constants unless I bring them to the specific scope of in-need-of-that-data function, and modifying globals seems to not work at all. **WHY?**

I know general cons of global variables, but in my usecase (storing some adresses and arrays that **literally are essential for the whole script to work at any given time**) it seems hilarious to read data like that from file or database, it just won't save any resources or help to avoid mistakes, and I'm guessing it will actually make it longer and more resource-hungry to make 56 calls to read a file that contains 2 strings instead of looking for it in RAM. Hard coding them in every single function seems like a nightmare to edit later in case of any changes. **What should I do to access/modify global data and share it between different functions, like in C or JS?** Or should I just rebuild the damn thing using a better way of accesing data like that (function that serves the data depending on given parameters would be even more RAM and CPU consuming to call, wouldn't it?)

The script that I was developing when approached the problem looks as follows:

```
<?php
static $client_id = "?&client_id=numbersAndStuff&callback=";
static $source  = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/";
static $source2 = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/";
static $direc = "/home/tybin/public_html/assets/data/twitch/";
$nicks = array();
$activityData;
$imageData;
function getNicknames()
    {
        global $direc,$nicks;
        $loc_direc = $direc;
        $fn = $loc_direc . "nicks.txt"; //works fine, not sure if 
        //its being done properly though
        $fileHandle = fopen($fn,r) or die ("Unable to load nicks.txt!");
        foreach(fgets($fileHandle) as $nick)
        {
            $loc_nicks = $nick;
            $nicks[] = $loc_nicks;
        }
        var_dump($nicks);
    }
//...20 other functions making use of data stored in nicks[] that I try to properly 
//initalise and directories to work in/get data from.
```

Comment: Rewrite it and use an object instead. Storing stuff in global scope is bad in any lang not just PHP, JS, or C...

Comment: What is the difference? I mean, wouldn't the object be globally defined and therefore rendered not accesible/modifiable from functions, just as the normal variables?

Comment: Yeah, obviously it will be globally defined but allows for dependency injection and IoC, so you init it once and then you pass its instance to what ever needs it. Solving your issue. The problem with "functions" are that whats defined inside is contained within its scope and would lead you what your doing `global` or using `$GLOBALS`..

Answer (score 0):

PHP files are only executed if you do so explicitly, otherwise they are completely ignored (unlike in C, for example).. So you should probably put the global stuff into a file reserved for that purpose, then use something like require_once() wherever you need it.. It may also make sense to wrap the access to the global into a function, so that you may change the implementation more easily, should the need arise..

```
// globals.php:
<?php

// define is best for true constants.. maybe move this into a config.php..
define('CLIENT_ID', '?&client_id=numbersAndStuff&callback=');
define('STREAMS_SOURCE', 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/');
define('USERS_SOURCE', 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/');
define('DIREC', '/home/tybin/public_html/assets/data/twitch/);

function getNicknames() {
    static $nicks = false;

    if (!is_array($nicks)) {
        $nicks = array();
        // load the data as before
    }

    return $nicks
}
```

And then elsewhere:

```
<?php
require_once('globals.php');

$nicks = getNicknames();
var_dump($nicks);
```

If you wrap the data in a function like that, you can also use `static`, avoiding polluting the global namespace..

Comment: The define keyword gets the job done, but still the array issue stays in place: I wasn't even aware of define, so I looked up its documentation, it is possible to declare an array using define but only if using PHP 7.0 which is not the case in my example because of backward-compatibility of some libraries. I'm not oblivious to the PHP scripts processing and allocating memory conditions,  it's irrelevant: your solution still uses resources, in this case needed to call a function, get through parsing it, then accesing the data and returning it whereas global variable cuts the first 2 steps.

Comment: The `is_array()` check will make it only load the data once, so the overhead is quite minimal. How many times do you expect to call this?